# How to access environment variable in androidManifest.xml using react-native-config

Tags: android, react-native, environment-variables

I'm using react-native-config npm for environment property. I can able to access the environment property in `JS` file. I am unable to access it in androidManifest.xml. I followed through the instruction.

**.env**

```
SCHEME = http
HOST = app.com
```

**buildgradlew**

```
defaultConfig {
resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.geo.vendor"
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<data android:scheme="SCHEME"
              android:host="HOST"/>
```

Comment: Did you add "project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle" to the android/app/build.gradle as well? as per https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config

Comment: Yes, I added all the step from the docs

Answer (score 1):

According to [their docs](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config#advanced-android-setup), the `"build_config_package"` setting is only for the Android package name / applicationId, not for other values such as the one you are trying to set.

Try it like this:

**.env**

```
SCHEME=http
HOST=app.com
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<data android:scheme="@string/SCHEME"
          android:host="@string/HOST"/>
```